# Understanding config.js produced by jspm install

Tags: javascript, jspm, systemjs

I am trying to understand the below content in config.js file created by jspm install. I have followed the [Config api](https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs/blob/master/docs/config-api.md#paths) but could not make out much with the description that is there. Looking at the folders created and packages installed .. looks like there is some kind of relation between paths and map options.

```
System.config({
  baseURL: "/",
  defaultJSExtensions: true,
  transpiler: "typescript",
  paths: {
    "github:*": "jspm_packages/github/*",
    "npm:*": "jspm_packages/npm/*"
  },

  map: {
    "typescript": "npm:typescript@1.6.0-dev.20150825",
    "github:jspm/nodelibs-buffer@0.1.0": {
      "buffer": "npm:buffer@3.4.3"
    },
    "github:jspm/nodelibs-os@0.1.0": {
      "os-browserify": "npm:os-browserify@0.1.2"
    },
    "github:jspm/nodelibs-path@0.1.0": {
      "path-browserify": "npm:path-browserify@0.0.0"
    },
    "github:jspm/nodelibs-process@0.1.1": {
      "process": "npm:process@0.10.1"
    },
    "npm:buffer@3.4.3": {
      "base64-js": "npm:base64-js@0.0.8",
      "ieee754": "npm:ieee754@1.1.6",
      "is-array": "npm:is-array@1.0.1"
    },
    "npm:os-browserify@0.1.2": {
      "os": "github:jspm/nodelibs-os@0.1.0"
    },
    "npm:path-browserify@0.0.0": {
      "process": "github:jspm/nodelibs-process@0.1.1"
    },
    "npm:typescript@1.6.0-dev.20150825": {
      "buffer": "github:jspm/nodelibs-buffer@0.1.0",
      "child_process": "github:jspm/nodelibs-child_process@0.1.0",
      "fs": "github:jspm/nodelibs-fs@0.1.2",
      "os": "github:jspm/nodelibs-os@0.1.0",
      "path": "github:jspm/nodelibs-path@0.1.0",
      "process": "github:jspm/nodelibs-process@0.1.1",
      "readline": "github:jspm/nodelibs-readline@0.1.0"
    }
  }
});
```

Can some body help me out with understanding the config? Please bear with me .. I am a beginner trying to understand the javascript ecosystem.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question but I will answer anyway if someone else runs into here.

Let's say the script runs into this definition within `map`: 
`github:jspm/nodelibs-buffer@0.1.0`

The parser will go and and check `github:*` entry in `paths` and replace it with the value `jspm_packages/github/*` there (like regex), and resulting with:
`jspm_packages/github/jspm/nodelibs-buffer@0.1.0`

When loading files and etc, System.js will be able to find where scripts are installed with this information.